# Make image smaller and preserve proportions?

Tags: javascript, html, css, browser, layout

I have a table column where I have this image displayed:

```
 <table width="200px" height="300px" align="center">
  <tr>
   <td><img src="...."></td>
  </tr>
 </table>
```

The image source is dynamic, so the image is not always the same size...

This means I have to (in most cases) resize the image to become smaller than it is.

How can I do this while preserving the proportions, in the easiest way?

Thanks

Comment: don't set the dimensions; let the browser decide its size.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just set a `width`.

```
<img src="..." style="width: 200px">
```

the proportions will be preserved automatically if you specify only one dimension.

Answer (score 2):

[Aspect ratio](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect_ratio_%28image%29) should be [preserved](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css3-images/#sizing) if you specify either a `width` or a `height`, but not both, in your `<img>` element's style:

> If the specified size is just a
>   definite width or just a definite
>   height, then the CSS View Box must
>   have the same width or height, as
>   appropriate. The other dimension is
>   calculated as follows:
>
> 1. If the object has an intrinsic aspect ratio, the CSS View Box must
>      have the same aspect ratio.

Answer (score 0):

Put id="imageID" on your img tab and call the following javascript:

```
  var elem = document.getElementById('imageID');
  if (elem == undefined || elem == null) return false;
  if (max == undefined) max = 100;
  if (elem.width > elem.height) {
    if (elem.width > max) elem.width = max;
  } else {
    if (elem.height > max) elem.height = max;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried the % instead of width/height in px ie.

```
<img src="..." style="width: 90%">
```